# Fatal Exception: Main android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID

Tags: android, error-handling

Android throwing an error: what does this mean?

```
02-27 19:57:57.935: E/AndroidRuntime(14261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 19:57:57.935: E/AndroidRuntime(14261): Process: com.vamC.jdbc, PID: 14261
02-27 19:57:57.935: E/AndroidRuntime(14261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vamC.jdbc/classification.ClassificationTest}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
02-27 19:57:57.935: E/AndroidRuntime(14261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
02-27 19:57:57.935: E/AndroidRuntime(14261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2183)
02-27 19:57:57.935: E/AndroidRuntime(14261):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:136)
```

Comment: it means something you are trying to used using `R.id.****` couldn't be found in that context.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have initialised an id which is not in the current activity layout.